# All products get original price zero after payment with paypal express in magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento-2.1, paypal-express

When payment method is paypal express, the items of the order get original price zero. All the other values ( subtotal, row tota, item status=invoicedl etc. ) remain correct. With any other payment method the orders are as expected.
Two weeks ago I made magento update from 2.1.8 to 2.1.9. At the same time I had to adjust again paypal express because it was disabled. In period before update the paypal behavior was correct.
Is it problem of paypal or magento 2.1.9 ?

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same issue, interestingly it only seems to occur if the user selects PayPal during the checkout (on www.domain.com/checkout/#payment)

If the user uses the 'PayPal - Checkout Now' buttons that can be displayed on the product page, cart and mini cart, the order values are correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, the customer does not want the 'PayPal - Checkout Now' buttons on cart or mini cart. Do you know if the problem is solved in version 2.2?